# Validation Typo3 Flow

Tags: php, fluid, typo3-flow

I have a question about the procedure of the flow validation.

When I submit my form and then flow shows a validation error for example for the url input field without deleting all the already inserted user inputs from the fields.

How does flow keep the field filled out? 
Which methods / classes are involved? Is there a way I can influence / copy this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your controller extends `\TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Controller\ActionController`, and by default in case there are validation errors `errorAction()` from this controller is called. Inside there is `forwardToReferringRequest()` just read the code to get it.

If you want to change this behaviour you can override `errorAction()` in your controller (same as any other protected/public method). You can also change `$errorMethodName` and handle it using different action on your controller level. Check this example https://wiki.typo3.org/Flow_Cookbook#handling_validation_errors_that_occur